# Localhost connecting to self on port 1111. Virus or ok?

Tags: windows-8, virus, anti-virus

When I run `netstat -a` on Windows 8.1 I am seeing a number of connections from 127.0.0.1: ports around 50000 connecting to My PC name (DadsPC) on port 1111. A portion are listed below. Is this normal? I've run anti-virus scans and am running Kaspersky AV but nothing was reported.

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50846        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50847        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50848        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50849        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50850        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50851        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50852        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50853        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50854        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50860        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50864        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50871        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50872        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50879        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50880        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50883        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50884        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50885        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50886        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50887        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50888        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50892        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50893        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50897        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50899        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50901        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50904        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50906        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50909        DadsPC:nfsd-status  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50911        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50912        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50913        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50914        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50915        DadsPC:nfsd-status  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50918        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50919        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50920        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50921        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50922        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50923        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50924        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50925        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50926        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50928        DadsPC:1111        TIME_WAIT
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 1111 can be used by quite a number of things. Apparently IANA has assigned it to lmsocialserver, it is also used by Adobe [Flash Media Administration server](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WSdb9a8c2ed4c02d261d76cb3412a40a490be-8000.html).

According to [speedgude.net](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1111) there are also a number of trojans that use this port as well. Your best option is to use `netstat -a -b`. The `-b` option should show you the executable that is actually listening on the port.

Answer (score 0):

There is no threat in your netstat results, since source and destination addresses are same and Kaspersky hasn't detect a problem. So, you're not victim of a major virus .

If you suspect being watched by someone, simply you should only allow trusted applications in firewall .

P.S. : Firewall looks at inbound and outbound network traffic on your windows and only allows safe traffic in. Outbound traffic is usually allowed, so badwared could send data freely. Responded data is assumed to be safe by Firewall so badware gets response easily. But, if you restrict outband traffic to only some trusted applications, you are good to go ;)

Comment: You are making the assumption that if the anti-virus doesn't warn of malware, the computer is clean. This is _not_ a good assumption. Malware authors take antivirus software into account, and come up with ways to get around it.

Comment: As I mentioned it's not a MAJOR virus, and since computer name is "DadsPC", I think there's no corporate threat involved.

Comment: Kaspersky does fine for home users. Most home users get paranoid when you show them some real-deal professional ways to confirm. Believe me, I've seen some of them formatting every bit of their hard drive to avoid being arrested for downloaded application cracks :)